# Drupal: installing it in a subfolder

Tags: drupal

this is a question about drupal installation on server.

I usually upload my drupal into a subfolder "drupal" and I ask my customers to check the website in such subfolders until when it is ready. Then I asl to change the default folder in Apache to the "drupal" one.

Sometimes my customer cannot change Apache configuration, so I was wondering if I can use a php script to forward users from root folder to the drupal one, or I should move the website to the root folder (which I would prefer to avoid, because is time consuming).

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [Taking your site live](http://drupal.org/node/135206)

Answer (score 1):

Can't you do the redirection in cpanel, or in `.htaccess`?

In that way you won't touch your drupal code.

Comment: We usually go the .htaccess route, using URL rewriting to 'hide' the subfolder from the outside world (The link provided by Nikit explains this as well). An added benefit of this is that it allows you to have multiple versions of the site installed in parallel folders which you can 'switch' on and off by means of a small change in the .htaccess.